# CSS class for specific list item

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add a CSS class to a specific nav menu item (li) if the latest post of a certain custom post type is not older than one week.

This is what I got so far. It works fine but adds the CSS class to all menu items. How do I target a specific li by id?

```
function blog_menu_item_new_posts( $classes, $item ) {
   global $wpdb;

   $latest_post = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT post_date FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'blogposts' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1" );

   $latest_post_date = strtotime($latest_post);
   $threshold = strtotime("-1 week");

   if ( $latest_post_date >= $threshold ) {
     array_push( $classes, "new-posts" );
   }

   return $classes;
}

add_filter( "nav_menu_css_class", "blog_menu_item_new_posts", 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code to target only a specific menu item by id (in this case id 101):

```
function blog_menu_item_new_posts( $classes, $item ) {
   global $wpdb;

   $latest_post = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT post_date FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'blogposts' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,1" );

   $latest_post_date = strtotime($latest_post);
   $threshold = strtotime("-1 week");

   if ( ( $latest_post_date >= $threshold ) && ($item->ID == 101) ) {
    array_push( $classes, "new-posts" );
   }

   return $classes;
}

add_filter( "nav_menu_css_class", "blog_menu_item_new_posts", 10, 2 );
```